# SelfSigned Certificate not working on first load in IE9

Tags: internet-explorer, iis-7, certificate, ssl-certificate, self-signed

I have self-signed certificate and I have installed certificate in trusted root in my local machine.
Everything works in Firefox and Chrome, but from IE first time when I open site I got exception "The remote server returned an error: NotFound" and as soon as I refresh browser it starts working correctly.
So it only does not work in IE first time. When I refresh browser it starts working correctly.

Can someone help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Self-Signed Certificate might have the wrong common name.  I just solved this problem for myself.

[how to set up SSL for Apache for a Mac so I can test Cross Domain iFrame on IE8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14508336/how-to-set-up-ssl-for-apache-for-a-mac-so-i-can-test-cross-domain-iframe-on-ie8/14515474#14515474)